# How to control bar span on pgfgantt's ganttbar?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfgantt, gantt

I would like to do Gantt chart in Latex thus I'm studying http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfgantt/pgfgantt.pdf, so far I can do:

[image]

by coding:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\begin{document}
\begin{ganttchart}[hgrid,vgrid,time slot format=isodate,time slot unit=month,x unit=10mm
]{2018-09-01}{2019-06-31} \gantttitlecalendar{year, month=shortname} \\

    \ganttbar{Task 1               }{2018-09-01}{2018-10-15} \\
    \ganttbar{Task 2 - Do something}{2018-11-01}{2018-12-31} \\
    \ganttbar{Something else       }{2019-01-01}{2019-02-28} \\
    \ganttbar{Another task         }{2019-03-01}{2019-04-30}
\end{ganttchart}
\end{document}
```

Actually, I was expecting `Task 1` bar to go just until mid Oct (`2018-10-15`). Why it fills all October?

I set `time slot unit=day,x unit=.4mm` and managed to get:

[image]

The down side is that `vgrid` is not there. Using it makes a mess:

[image]

Perhaps its possible to limit the amount of vertical lines?

Answer (score 1):

You can set a style list for the grid (see page 9 of the manual), for example to draw only 1 in every 11 lines.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\begin{document}
\begin{ganttchart}[hgrid,vgrid={*{10}{draw=none},*1{black, dotted}},time slot format=isodate,time slot unit=day,x unit=.4mm
]{2018-09-01}{2019-06-31} \gantttitlecalendar{year, month=shortname} \\

    \ganttbar{Task 1               }{2018-09-01}{2018-10-15} \\
    \ganttbar{Task 2 - Do something}{2018-11-01}{2018-12-31} \\
    \ganttbar{Something else       }{2019-01-01}{2019-02-28} \\
    \ganttbar{Another task         }{2019-03-01}{2019-04-30}
\end{ganttchart}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: They don't match with month's begin/end?

Comment: They don't, I didn't know that you wanted that :)